# How to connect to MySQL db in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I tried it this way to connect to a database using MySQL, however when I run the code `Response.Write` does not write anything at all to the website.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        // if it is not a post back method, page renders for first time 
        {
            connectdb();
        }
    }

    private void connectdb()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "first_db";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Response.Write("connection opened");
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
            //on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    Response.Write("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    Response.Write("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
        }
    } //end of connectdb 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging, stepping through the code line by line to see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is suppressing lots of exception possibilities.

I suggest you add this to the end of your switch statement.

```
      default:
                Response.Write(ex.Number + ": " + ex.Message);
                break;
```

You'll likely find out what's wrong.